# Neopixel led strip stops responding after change in brightness

Tags: arduino-uno, led, neopixel

I have an arduino UNO hooked up to a neopixel LED strip with 148 lights.  Most of the time it works fine, but when I upload a program that changes the brightness frequently, particularly when I increase brightness, only the first 8 LEDs continue responding.  The rest get stuck.

Here's an example of the kind of code that sets this issue off.  To fix it, I usually have to restart the lights and the arduino and sometimes upload a blank program to the arduino.

I'm pretty new to arduino programming so and help would be really appreciated.  Thank you.

```
#include "FastLED.h"

FASTLED_USING_NAMESPACE 

// FAST LED definitions
#define DATA_PIN    3
#define LED_TYPE    WS2812B
#define COLOR_ORDER GRB
#define NUM_LEDS    148

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];
#define DATA_PIN 3 // Output Pin to Data Line on Strip

int fadeAmount = 5;  
int brightness = 0;

void setup()
{
   FastLED.addLeds<LED_TYPE,DATA_PIN,COLOR_ORDER>(leds, NUM_LEDS).setCorrection(TypicalLEDStrip);
}

void loop()
{
   for(int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++ )
   {
   leds[i].setRGB(0,255,0);  
   leds[i].fadeLightBy(brightness);
  }
  FastLED.show();
  brightness = brightness + fadeAmount;
  // reverse the direction of the fading at the ends of the fade:
  if(brightness == 0 || brightness == 255)
  {
    fadeAmount = -fadeAmount ;
  }   
  delay(20);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing more research and getting feedback on the Adafruit forum [here](https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=91214&p=459815), it appears that the problem was a cracked solder joint.  I managed to get access to the strip and wiggled it a little and the problem has gone away.  The recommendation is to reflow the joint by adding a little solder over the data connection between where the LEDs stop being responsive.

Comment: If it's only the solder, you can indeed resolder/reflow it.
At one of my strips, the solder-joint ripped out some of the strip, then it will be best to cut out the pixel completely. You can easily re-attach them (without the single pixel).

Comment: You might indeed also check the heat generation, if it becomes hot enough to reflow the solder, it won't last long.

Comment: I replaced the pixel and the set up appears to be working without issue now.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost certainly a power issue. The [Adafruit page](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2547) about one of those types of Neopixels says:

> Don't forget, with 256 LEDs, you could use over 15A of current if you turn on all the LEDs on to white (which we really do not recommend because we don't think the flex PCB can handle that much current). Try to keep the current draw at under 5A ...

Increasing the brightness increases the current drawn. Do you have a heavy-duty power supply? Are the connecting leads sufficient for (say) 8 amps of current?

---

### New information based on comments made

Based on comments by Lorenz I now think it is more likely to be that they are overheating.

> I have the strip embedded in a picture frame with epoxy resin over it.

That makes it difficult for the ICs to cool down, and LEDs generate heat. If you search for "neopixels heat" you find quite a few matches. Some suggestions made are to use a heat sink or a fan. If this isn't practical for you, then running at a lower PWM rate (ie. not as bright) and not as saturated colour, could help keep the heat down.

You don't want to "cook" one of the early pixels, because each one has to pass the data on to the next one in sequence, so if you lose an early one, you lose everything after it, particularly if you can't get at it to replace one.

---

### Postscript regarding heat

I have been testing a NeoPixel with a temperature sensor. Displaying full white (255/255/255) it has reached about 44°C. So clearly it warms up. However this is in the open air with just some sticky-tape holding the sensor onto the LED. According to the spec the chip can operate at up to 80°C, so this is within range.

However if the whole thing was sealed in epoxy, then the heat being generated would have much less chance of escaping into the ambient air, and thus would be likely to get a lot hotter.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm good on the power supply side.  I have a 5V 10A supply hooked up (https://www.adafruit.com/products/658).

Comment: What do you mean by are the connecting leads sufficient for (say) 8 amps of current?

Comment: I'm using basic jumper wires (https://www.adafruit.com/products/1957) connected through a 2.1mm DC barrel jack and a mini breadboard.

Comment: I see. From that page `Each wire is 28 AWG (7 strands @ 36 AWG)` and from  [Wire Gauge and Current Limits Including Skin Depth and Strength](http://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm) 28 AWG wire has a maximum of 1.4 amps for chassis wiring. Thus I suspect your wiring cannot carry the load. Try measuring the voltage on the Neopixel end (ie. at the end of the wire). I am guessing that, when the brightness is up, you won't be getting 5V there.

Comment: Nick - I've rewired the neopixel wires to go directly to the 5v power supply without any jumper cables in between.  I'm still getting the problem.  I have the strip embedded in a picture frame with epoxy resin over it.  I cannot actually get to the other end of the strip to measure the voltage there.  Is it possible that the epoxy enclosure is causing the LED to overheat.  Usually the strip works fine for a few minutes (if I haven't plugged it in in a while) and then craps out.  Any thoughts on how I might be able to fix this without tearing up the frame?

Comment: With a lot of current going through them overheating sounds like a possibility. Do you have a way of measuring the heat of them (eg. a contact thermometer)? You could try setting the code to operate them at a low power level for a while, to see if it is heat, or time, that is causing this. Also, can't you at least measure the power input voltage to the frame?

Comment: The input voltage is 5V.  I've measured it and it's pretty constant.  Time definitely seems to be a factor.  When I run the lights at lower power, they last much longer and when I don't run them for a while and then run them, they last longer too.  After they crap out, only the first 8 respond to the pulsing pattern and the rest just stay lit at the color they were the moment it crapped out.  I'm trying to figure out what I can do to remedy this situation.  The LEDs are completely encased in wood and epoxy so there's very little air circulation around the strip.

Comment: My understanding of NeoPixels is that the early ones have to take the incoming data, strip out one RGB sequence, and pass the others on. Thus the earlier ones have more to do than the later ones, and if an early one fails, the later ones will do nothing. This would tend to explain what you are seeing.

Comment: Can you think of anything I can do to fix the situation?

Comment: If you can measure the temperature you could confirm it is indeed getting hot. And to fix it, if it is all encased in epoxy, all I can suggest doing is running at low brightness so it doesn't heat up too much.

Comment: Nick - one more question for you.  When I have this issue, the LEDs continue to be fully lit.  It's just the data that doesn't seem to go past the first 8 LEDs.  The remain 140 LEDs stay lit and bright they just stop responding to the pattern.  Would this suggest something other than a power issue?

Comment: I presume the LEDs "remember" the last colour latched into them. With power applied they would continue to show that. If data doesn't go past the first 8, it would seem likely that the 8th one has overheated and stopped passing the data on.

Comment: See amended post regarding measuring the temperature of the pixel when operating.